# Adding a UITabBarController to an UIViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a sample application on http://github.com/niklassaers/Test-iPhone-TabBar-App that shows my problem: I have a regular view-based application, and at some point (in this case when I click a button) I want to load a tabbar controller and display it. I believe this is what I should be doing:

```
MyTabBarController *tabs = [[MyTabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBar" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:tabs.view];
```

Unfortunately, this brings up a bit of black in the bottom of my main view and nothing more. I believed it should bring up the tabbar, the tabs, and the selected view. What is the correct way of loading a TabBarController (or making a TabBar controller if that's what I've done wrong) in a view-based application?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: do you have TabBar.xib file in the source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a UINavigationController, then just push the tabs controller onto the nav controller when you're ready to display it.

Comment: Can I use the nav controller without having the navbar?

Comment: Here's a tutorial that may help: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/

Comment: Sure, just use [UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:]

Comment: I'm afraid you may be misusing the viewController class. In general, on iPhone, ViewControllers are used to control full (or nearly full, excluding top and bottom bars) views. Thus, if you want to bring in a new view controller, it will control almost everything on screen. You'll need to create and add a new button in the Tabbed controller.